# How do I force knitr to delete support directory (.png files) after HTML is knitted

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, knitr

```
RStudio Edition : Preview
RStudio Version : 1.2.1335
OS Version      : Windows 7 Pro
R Version       : 3.5.3
```

When I knit `.Rmd` files to `.html` in R Studio two items are created in the parent directory:

1. the desired file e.g. `project-name.html`
2. an undesired directory of supporting `.png` files called `\...\project-name_files`

I assume this `\project-name_files` should be auto-deleted, but this is not happening. If I try and delete this `\project-name_files` directory my `project-name.html` file also gets deleted.

The `\project-name_files` directory and `project-name.html` are solidly linked in a way I didn't even know was possible. If I move either **individually** from location A to location B on my hard drive they follow each other, both get moved, as if they were permanently linked. I've only selected one, how are they both moving? I've never seen anything like this and don't know how the Windows O/S even allows it! I know there are symbolic links but this is more like a permanent invisible link.

Anyways, if this is expected behavior I won't file a bug report (is it?). If it is expected behavior how do I disable it? I'd prefer the directory of support files (`.png`s) is deleted after the `.html` file is created.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0  
[3] dplyr_0.8.0.1   purrr_0.3.2    
[5] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3    
[7] tibble_2.1.1    ggplot2_3.1.1  
[9] tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0
 [3] pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.3  
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.5.3     
 [7] packrat_0.5.0    jsonlite_1.6    
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4  gtable_0.3.0    
[11] nlme_3.1-137     lattice_0.20-38 
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4     
[15] cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10 
[17] haven_2.1.0      withr_2.1.2     
[19] xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.4.0      
[21] generics_0.0.2   hms_0.4.2       
[23] grid_3.5.3       tidyselect_0.2.5
[25] glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0        
[27] readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4    
[29] magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.4 
[31] scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.3     
[33] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1
[35] stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2  
[37] munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.2     
[39] crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Aren't those the images that the HTML file links to? Have you set it up as self-contained HTML? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#document-dependencies

Comment: These are the `.png` images knitr creates of my plots that are 'knit' into the HTML. I never specified that dependencies should be in external files with `self_contained: false`. It looks like this is a 'feature' of Windows. Get me back to Linux please! And thanks for the tip. still researching... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/manage#connected

Comment: What "self_contained" does is embed the images into the HTML code. Otherwise, HTML is generally done where image tags point to the path of an image file. Without those image files at the expected path, the images won't be able to display.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Didn't know that. But these `.png` are just the images of my plots, directly generated from my R code. If I rename my `.html` file, I am able to independently move it to new separate locations, and it will display properly, even without the supporting directory. On Linux if I run the same `.Rmd` this supporting directory is created and immediately deleted after the `.html` is complete. I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: But they're the images being displayed in your output document? Maybe you can put an example together

Comment: If you're on a Win7 machine please `File > New File > New R Markdown`. Save this file as `no-delete-test.Rmd`. Then knit via `Ctrl-Shift-K`. What I get is (1) the expected `no-delete-test.html` and the unexpected (2) `\no-delete-test` directory, that itself contains only one directory and one item, that being `\no-delete-test\figure-html\pressure-1.png`. On Linux this entire `\no-delete-test` directory and contents are deleted after knitr is complete. Can you reproduce? Must be a bug?

Comment: Sorry, on a Mac. Try over at the RStudio forums, since it seems like this might not be a code issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When in doubt, try to upgrade your packages.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) This is [a known bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1553) in **rmarkdown** v1.12 (your session info didn't show the version of **rmarkdown**), and has been fixed a while ago on Github. The current CRAN version of **rmarkdown**, [v1.13](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/releases/tag/v1.13), contains the bug fix.

Comment: I was on v1.12 and upgrading to v1.13 solved the issue.